# Edit CheckBox and EditText located in another XML file

Tags: android, xml

So I'm in activity Home which has:

```
setContentView(R.layout.home);
```

Now, from Home activity, one can go to Settings activity which has:

```
setContentView(R.layout.settings);
```

It has a couple of CheckBoxes and EditTexts.

Is it possible to edit the state of those checkboxes from the Home activity?

I already declared them in Home like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

Which finds the ID just fine but the application crashes on the line where I try to

```
checkBox1.setChecked(true);
```

Is it not possible to access it from another activity??

Thank you

Comment: it means you have to send some data to the next activity right??

Comment: @Rashmi
I wanted to avoid that, but since people up to now have answered that it is not possible to alter values of other xml files then I will have to send data to the other activity which actually uses the xml file and then that activity will apply the values :)

Comment: yes the only the way to pass data between acivities is intents..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an activity cannot directly modify view elements of another activity, since Android makes no guarantees regarding the lifecycle of each activity. Activity A may invoke Activity B, but if memory is running low while B is displayed, A may be destroyed.

You will need to use intents to pass data from one activity to another.

Comment: thanks. that alternative solution was in my mind, but figured it'd be much easier the way I tried to

Comment: It should've been able to edit the xml file BEFORE display. In my case, it should've been able to add/delete the attribute "android:checked="false" of that specific id.

Answer (score 1):

pass data between activity

for ex: **Main.java**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Home.this,Setting.class);
i.putExtra("check","true"); <-------- set valuse here
            ^^^^    ^^^^
startActivity(i);
```

and in **Setting.java**

```
String str = getIntent().getExtras().getString("check");
                                                 ^^^^
```

Comment: Yes thanks for the tip, I was just looking whether it is possible with that way.